# How to Get Body content of HTTPS using CURL

Tags: php, curl, https

The following code will retrieve the body content of a url retrieved using CURL in php but not https. Can anyone tell me how I edit the code as I need to get the data returned not just the header.

From the test I did here is the result. You can see it has a content-length, I just don't know how to access it.

Thanks
Stephen

Errors: 0

string(1457) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Sat, 01 Aug 2009 06:32:11 GMT Server: Apache/1.3.41 (Darwin) PHP/5.2.4 mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.7l Cache-Control: max-age=60 Expires: Sat, 01 Aug 2009 06:33:11 GMT Last-Modified: Thu, 23 Nov 2006 17:44:53 GMT ETag: "97d620-44b-4565de15" Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 1099 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html "

```
<?php

$curl_handle=curl_init();

$username = "";
$password = "";

$fullurl = "http://www.queensberry.com";
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fullurl);

   $returned = curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close ($ch);
   var_dump($returned);


?>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the solution:
Try this, just keep rest of the coding same as above...

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fullurl);

$returned = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($returned);
```

Changing CURLOPT_HEADER to 0 makes it so that only the page content is returned.

Answer (score 3):

I look for the length of the header using the curl's getinfo.  Then substring the response:

```
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$start = $info['header_size'];
$body = substr($result, $start, strlen($result) - $start);
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't `$fullurl` be "https://www.queensberry.com" ?

When I changed `$fullurl` as stated and ran the code, `var_dump` displayed the "under construction" page.

Comment: Thanks Josh

Yes it should be https:// but that wasn't the problem. It needed some extra parameters added I think. One of my staff got it working. I'll have to get him to share code here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you still need the header, which means setting CURLOPT_HEADER to 0 is not an option, you can find the start of the body by looking for an empty line (two CRLF). See the spec: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html

so this should do the job:

```
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $start = strpos($data, "\r\n\r\n") + 4;
    $body = substr($data, $start, strlen($data) - $start);
```